# Unity | Slider OnDeselect

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите информацию.
Есть класс "RotateHolder".Он хранит ссылку на объект Slider.Мне нужно узнавать когда ползунок слайдера перестает двигаться игроком.Да, существует IEndDragHandler, но я не знаю как его получить через ссылку на объект Slider.
Через ссылку на Slider я вижу, что можно вызывать метод OnDeselect(), но я не могу понять какие аргументы в эти метод прописывать.Спасибо

Comment: Я не гуру, но подозреваю как и во всех прочих ЯП ```Slider.OnEndDrag = function```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно создать новый класс, сделать его наследником класса Slider, затем реализовать интерфейс IEndDragHandler. Класс CustomSlider вешаем на объект slider (вместо базового класса Slider).

```
public class CustomSlider : Slider, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("End Drag");
    }
}
```